# Trying to create an alias or function for nohub spark-submit

Tags: bash, apache-spark

Trying to create an alias or function for nohub spark-submit & I am getting an error back:

```
[hadoop@ip-172-31-82-184 ~]$ function nhsubmit { nohup spark-submit --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.7.0 --driver-memory 20g --executor-memory 20g "$@" output.log 2>&1 & }
[hadoop@ip-172-31-82-184 ~]$ export -f nhsubmit
[hadoop@ip-172-31-82-184 ~]$ nhsubmit spark_hlper.py
-bash: spark_hlper.py: command not found
```

I really am bad with bash. Thanks,

Comment: Have you changed the permissions for `spark_hlper.py`? Is that executable?

Comment: Good Q but spark-submit does not need spark_hlper.py to be an executable

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/nohup spark-submit --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.7.0 --driver-memory 20g --executor-memory 20g $1 > output.log 2>&1 &
```

And running it with
`$ ./tst.sh tst.py`
works